# Python : Joining separated numeric characters in text but leave alphabetic texts

Tags: python, string, python-3.6

I've some sample strings like :

```
sample_lt1 = 'CANCEL Bitcoin kev 1 96 35 2 0 5 7 5 6'
sample_lt2 = 'CANCEL Bitcoln key 1 6 3 5 20 5 7 56 Cash 2 9 00'
sample_lt3 = 'CANCEL Bitcein key 0 1 5 0 0 4 4 1 6 Cash '
```

I'm trying to join the numbers separated by spaces in the string but leave the chunk of alphabetic characters. The desired output for those sample inputs would be :

```
sample_out1 = 'CANCEL Bitcoin kev 19635205756'
sample_out2 = 'CANCEL Bitcoln key 1635205756 Cash 2900'
sample_out3 = 'CANCEL Bitcein key 015004416 Cash ' # Removal of last space is ok.
```

Till now, I have done this :

```
def ReForm(lt):
    lts = lt.split()
    c = 0
    new = []
    temp = []
    while c<len(lts):
        if lts[c].isnumeric():
            temp.append(lts[c])
        else:
            if temp:
                s = ''.join(temp)
                new.append(s)
            new.append(lts[c])
        c += 1
    ret = ' '.join(new)
    return ret
```

The output given by my code is :

```
CANCEL Bitcoin kev
CANCEL Bitcoln key 1635205756 Cash
CANCEL Bitcein key 015004416 Cash
```

It fails to join the space separated numbers in the first and second case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex. --> `re.sub` with `Lookbehind & Lookahead`

**Ex:**

```
import re

sample_lt1 = 'CANCEL Bitcoin kev 1 96 35 2 0 5 7 5 6'
sample_lt2 = 'CANCEL Bitcoln key 1 6 3 5 20 5 7 56 Cash 2 9 00'
sample_lt3 = 'CANCEL Bitcein key 0 1 5 0 0 4 4 1 6 Cash '

data = [sample_lt1, sample_lt2, sample_lt3]

for i in data:
    print(re.sub(r"(?<=\d) (?=\d)", "", i))
```

**Output:**

```
CANCEL Bitcoin kev 19635205756
CANCEL Bitcoln key 1635205756 Cash 2900
CANCEL Bitcein key 015004416 Cash
```

Answer (score 1):

The following fixes your program:

```
def ReForm(lt):
    lts = lt.split()
    c = 0
    new = []
    temp = []
    while c<len(lts):
        if lts[c].isnumeric():
            temp.append(lts[c])
        else:
            if temp:
                s = ''.join(temp)
                new.append(s)
                temp = []
            new.append(lts[c])
        c += 1
    if temp:
        s = ''.join(temp)
        new.append(s)
    ret = ' '.join(new)
    return ret
```

What your loop was missing was a fallback case for when the last character was a number. In that case your `temp` list was not appended to `new`.
Another thing that was missing was catching the case where `temp` was added to the overall string but the string would continue with different content. This can be achieved by reinitializing `temp` in the loop.

Comment: Oh, I must have missed that. Will check it.

Comment: Got it working, there was 1 more initialization missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ReForm(lt):
    lts = lt.split()
    c = 0
    new = []
    temp = []
    while c<len(lts):
        if lts[c].isnumeric():
            temp.append(lts[c])
        else:
            if temp:
                s = ''.join(temp)
                new.append(s)
                temp = []
            new.append(lts[c])
        c += 1  
    if temp:
        s = ''.join(temp)
        new.append(s)                   
    ret = ' '.join(new)
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s1 = 'CANCEL Bitcoin kev 1 96 35 2 0 5 7 5 6'
print(re.sub(r"(?<=\d) (?=\d)", "", s1))
CANCEL Bitcoin kev 19635205756
s2 = 'CANCEL Bitcoln key 1 6 3 5 20 5 7 56 Cash 2 9 00'
print(re.sub(r"(?<=\d) (?=\d)", "", s2))
CANCEL Bitcoln key 1635205756 Cash 2900
```

Comment: Add some explanation to remove your answer from low quality post.